# Array of pointers unexplained behavior (with shallow copy) c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This is a behavior with array of pointers in C++ (GNU GCC compiler) that I can't find an explanation for, hopefully someone can clear the confusion.

I'm creating an array of pointers (arr_ptr), The pointers are pointing to valid data, then I create another array of pointers (arrcopy), I do -what I think- a shallow copy (arrcopy = arr_ptr), and I get the data as expected...so far so good.

The part I am not understanding is, after I delete arr_ptr, shouldn't arrcopy still be pointing to my valid data? Why this is not happening?
Thank you.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1; int b=2; int c=3;
    int* ap = &a; int* bp = &b; int* cp = &c;

    // Array of pointers
    int** arr_ptr = new int*[3];
    arr_ptr[0] = ap;
    arr_ptr[1] = bp;
    arr_ptr[2] = cp;

    //shallow copy
    int** arrcopy = arr_ptr;

    cout << "Values: " << *(arr_ptr[0]) << " " << *(arrcopy[0]) << endl;
    cout << "Addresses: " << arr_ptr[0] << " " << arrcopy[0] << endl;
    cout << endl;

    a++;

    cout << "After Incrementing a:" << endl;
    cout << *(arr_ptr[0]) << " " << *(arrcopy[0]) << endl;
    cout << arr_ptr[0] << " " << arrcopy[0] << endl;
    cout << endl;

    *(arr_ptr[0]) = 5;

    cout << "After updating a value to 5:" << endl;
    cout << *(arr_ptr[0]) << " " << *(arrcopy[0]) << endl;
    cout << arr_ptr[0] << " " << arrcopy[0] << endl;
    cout << endl;

    //so far so good - works as expected

    //deleting arr_ptr
    delete[] arr_ptr;

    // Why?: shouldn't arrcopy still be pointing to A
    cout << "Values: " << *(arr_ptr[0]) << " " << *(arrcopy[0]) << endl; //The result I am expecting here is: unknown_value  5
    cout << "Addresses: " << arr_ptr[0] << " " << arrcopy[0];
    cout << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

[image: arr_ptr Initialization]

**After Shallow copy of arr_ptr to arrcopy (arrcopy = arr_ptr)**
[image]

**After deleting arr_ptr, shouldn't arrcopy still be pointing to the memory locations of a,b,c data values?!**
[image]

Comment: The `delete[]` operator also calls the destructors of all elements in the array. I think you meant a simple `delete`?

Comment: `arrcopy = arr_ptr` means you have 2 pointers to the *same array*. Delete the array through one pointer and it is invalid for the other.

Comment: You didn't make a copy of the array, you only copied the pointer to the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have 2 arrays after the assignment you have 2 pointers to the same array:

```
arr_ptr -------->|ptr0|ptr1|ptr2|ptr3... (allocated memory)


arr_cpy = arr_ptr; // copy only the pointer
```

Now *both* pointers point to the *same allocated memory*:

```
arr_ptr -------->|ptr0|ptr1|ptr2|ptr3...
                   ^
arr_cpy -----------|


delete[] arr_ptr; // invalidate the memory that both pointers point to
```

This gives:

```
arr_ptr -------->|xxx0|xxx1|xxx2|xxx3... (invalid memory)
                   ^
arr_cpy -----------|
```

It doesn't matter which pointer you call `delete[]` on, they both point to the same block of allocated memory so after the call they both point to the same block of *invalidated* memory.

What you need to do is copy the whole array:

```
int** arr_cpy = new int*[3];
std::copy(arr_ptr, arr_ptr + 3, arr_cpy); // copy the pointers to the new array
```

Or **much better** use a `std::vector`:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1; int b=2; int c=3;
    int* ap = &a; int* bp = &b; int* cp = &c;

    // Array of pointers
    std::vector<int*> arr_ptr{3};
    arr_ptr[0] = ap;
    arr_ptr[1] = bp;
    arr_ptr[2] = cp;

    //shallow copy
    std::vector<int*> arr_cpy = arr_ptr; // copy the whole vector

    // ... etc.
```

No need for `delete[]`, memory is deallocated automatically when your vector goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `arr_ptr` nor `arrcopy` is an array. Both are just pointers.

A C++ pointer is a little overloaded. It can point to a single object or to an array of objects.

In your case `arr_ptr` is initialized with the address of the array that you allocated in the dynamic memory. But it could as well be initialized with an address of a single object on the stack:

```
int i = 0;
int** arr_ptr = &i;
```

By copying the value of that pointer into another pointer of the same type you simply have two pointers referring to the same memory location:

```
              // array in the heap
              [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]
              ^
             / \
            /   \
           /     \
       arr_ptr  arrcopy
```